# WordPress multisite - Bitnami

Tags: multisite, xampp

I usually install WordPress using the standard WordPress installer. I mainly use multisite.

I've just installed `xampp` by Bitnami and there seems to be a Bitnami WordPress installer they're offering.

Has anyone used one of these installers and can offer some advice on how they compare to the standard WordPress installers?

Just wondering if they save any time (not that the standard WordPress install is particularly lengthy!).

Comment: Be very careful with Bitnami deployment. They put in tag on the front page and then you can't find the path to delete it. Then they create the system to where you can change the email to the Super administration. Mine is user@example.com permanently.